# next-auth is not installing in my project(Nextjs, React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I use yarn create next-app for my nextjs in react project.But next-auth is not
installed in my project. My node version is LTS 16.15.1
and yarn version is 1.22.18, npm version is 8.9.0. I tried in latest version and old
version of nodejs but I am getting this error again and again.Kindly resolve my issue
how to install next-auth in my project.

```
   yarn add v1.22.18
   warning ../../../package.json: No license field
   [1/4] Resolving packages...
   [2/4] Fetching packages...
   error next-auth@4.3.4: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. 
   Expected version "^12.19.0 || ^14.15.0 || ^16.13.0". Got "18.2.0"
   error Found incompatible module.
   info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this 
   command.
```

Comment: From the error you can see that `next-auth` is only compatible with the following Node.js version range `^12.19.0 || ^14.15.0 || ^16.13.0`, which doesn't match your local Node.js version 18.2.0. Make sure you're on a compatible version.

Answer (score 0):

Got it from @pfcodes:
Add `--ignore-engines` flag for install and upgrade operations to get around this for now. [here](https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/issues/4575#issuecomment-1140043530)